# How to capture dynamics values which will be generated from loop in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have one scenario to test in which one transaction needs to be iterated for several times and then submit the request. For each iteration, I will get one detID (e.g: for 20 iterations - 20 unique detID). The problem is while submitting the request all the detID are been passing in the request parameters (example: if loop ran for 10 iterations then 10 detID are passing inside the request). I have put regular expression extractor to the transaction which is in loop which will capture all the mathces but it is capturing only the last one. (e.g: if loop ran for 10 iteration, regex capturing the 10th iteration value).
Please help me.I want to include these detID inside the submit request.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) before the request with the regex.
2. Add a BeanShell PostProcessor as a child of the request after the regex with the below code:

   `String ID = vars.get("ID");// ID is the reference name of your regex
   String Counter = vars.get("Counter");//  Counter is the reference name of your regex 
   vars.put("ID_"+ Counter, ID);`

You will have 20 different variables each one holds a different ID value and you can use them as ${ID_1} for the first ID and ${ID_2} for the second and so on.

Comment: Could you please explain it in more details?

Comment: Add a counter just before the request in the loop then add a beanshell postprocessor as a child of the request with the above configurations, what is it exactly that you dont understand so i can explain?

Comment: Issue resolved. I have understood. Thanks for your resposne